# Working with Polars list-type columns - how to use them in conditions?

Tags: list, python-polars

I find lists as a type extremely useful. Unfortunately, they are well documented - how to generate them, but not how to access the content itself :(

For example, I have a column named CARS:

```
CARS
list
[f64]
======
[1,2,3]
[2,3]
[4]
[]
```

I would like to prepare two new variables.

- CARF - the 1st value in the list
- CAR2 - 1 - if value=2 is at the first place, 2 - if 2 is present anywhere, 3 - 2 not present at all

Results should like:

```
CARF   CAR2
1      2   
2      1
4      3
Null   3
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `when -> then -> otherwise` expressions and the `list` namespace which consists of utilities for lists.

They are [documented here.](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/list.html)

Here is an example for your use case:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "cars": [[1,2,3], [2,3],[4],[]]
})

df.select(
    pl.col("cars").list.first().alias("cars_first"),
    pl.when(pl.col("cars").list.first() == 2)
    .then(1)
    .when(pl.col("cars").list.contains(2))
    .then(2)
    .otherwise(3).alias("cars_literal")
)
```

Outputs:

```
shape: (4, 2)
┌────────────┬──────────────┐
│ cars_first ┆ cars_literal │
│ ---        ┆ ---          │
│ i64        ┆ i32          │
╞════════════╪══════════════╡
│ 1          ┆ 2            │
│ 2          ┆ 1            │
│ 4          ┆ 3            │
│ null       ┆ 3            │
└────────────┴──────────────┘
```

Comment: The list documentation is now at: https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/dsl/list_context.html  The python API ref is at https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/array.html